# Modify the subnet mask of a network interface programmatically

Tags: networking

I want to modify the subnet mask of a network interface. I am able to get read the default mask using getifaddrs(). However, is there a way to write (and modify) ifa_netmask parameter? Does a socket function exist that can do the work? or maybe ioctl()?

Comment: Doing that is just asking for problems. The network masks must match for all the devices on the same network, otherwise not all devices may be able to communicate with each other.

Comment: What operating system do you use? The commands are different for Linux bash, Windows CMD/bat and PowerShell. Or do you wish to set it by some programming language and your special application? The network scripts are relatively simply a can be modified by easy way.

Comment: DigiBat I want to use C APIs to modify the subnet mask. I am working on QNX. I am aware of ifconfig <interface name> <IP> netmask <mask>. I just don't want to use system() to execute the cmd.